# При генерации, изображение первый раз не появляется

Tags: php

Добрый день. 
При автогенерации миниатюры, эта миниатюра начинает отображаться в браузере, но потом пропадает, браузер выдает значок отсутствия картинки http://f5.s.qip.ru/s6WVNjPh.png

После обновления страницы картинка отображает нормально. Проблема в браузерах Opera последняя, Google Chrome. В Firefox все хорошо.

Картинку отдаю в браузер так:

```
header('Content-type: image');
print file_get_contents($resized_filename);
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Поробуйте правильно написать шапку 'Content-type: image/jpeg' (если JPG) и 'Content-type: image/png' (если PNG) И используйте функцию readfile вместо print file_get_contents

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: что будет, если запросить картинку напрямую по URL в "режиме приватности"? подозреваю проблемы с кешированием.

Comment: И в приватном окне, и в обычном в любом браузере по прямой ссылке изображение генерируется сразу. http://site/images/500x250/filename.jpg - при замене размеров в адресе,  создается другая миниатюра и по прямой ссылке она отображается как надо. А на сайте нет...

Comment: Хоть изображение и отображается по прямой ссылке, но сервер отдает HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Попробуйте отдавать полный набор заголовков :

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php

только там файл отдаётся на скачивание

и используйте функцию readfile() для таких нужд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему можно решить, решая её.
Не гадая на кофейной гуще, а совершая какие-либо действия.

- В частности, можно обратиться к скрипту напрямую, и посмотреть, что он возвращает.
- Можно скачать с сервера $resized_filename и посмотреть что там внутри.
  можно посмотреть разницу между кодом, который генерирует изображение и кодом, который просто показывает, если оно уже есть.
- (Примечание: любая информация, полученная с помощью этих действий, предназначена в первую очередь не для написания комментариев к ответу, а для самого программиста. Он должен анализировать полученную информацию и предпринимать шаги для исправления)
- можно посмотреть, какие НТТР заголовки отдает сервер при успешном показе картинки и какие - при неуспешном. И сравнить

Все эти действия называются пониятием "отладка", и занимают значительный объем рабочего времени любого программиста. Увы, про отладку не рассказывают в видеоуроках и самоучителях "интернет-магазин за 24 часа". Но от этого она не становится менее обязательной.

Comment: Спасибо за наставления, но прежде чем написать сюда, я испробовал всевозможные варианты, которые пришли мне в голову и почти все, что вы перечислили. И после множества неудачных экспериментов с кодом, я решил узнать мнение более опытных специалистов.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ помог. Сервер возвращал ошибку 404. Пописал 200 ОК и все стало нормально.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
readfile($resized_filename);
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!